# Wireshark RST against TCP Zero Window

Tags: tcp, socket, wireshark, tcpdump, lync

During application sharing with Microsoft Lync Client (Mac OS X), TCP ACK with RST flag is sent from my application end to Lync end against TCP Zero Window packets and call gets dropped.

[Image Link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS0vh.png)

FYI:

```
My Application End: 172.16.6.106:55848
Lync End (Remote): 172.16.14.58:18627
Environment: 
My Application End: Centos/Linux
Lync End: Mac OSX
Shared Over Wifi.
```

Comment: So what is your question? This looks like a networking bottleneck to me.